# How can I make an asynchronous setState before following a Link?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I want to be able to 'capture' a selection of a user clicking a link that takes them to another page. I need the users selection to display a detail page of thebselected image.

I'm facing the problem that the browser follows the link before react updated the state "key". The state-Change of key is not passed to the details page. Is there an easy way to fix that without fetch?

```
export default class IGallery extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      countryList: [],
      wallet: "",
      key: "",
    };
  }
  handleClick = (_key) => {
    console.log("before setState", this.state.key);
    this.setState({ key: _key }, () =>
      console.log("after setState", this.state.key)
    );
  };
  render() {
    return (
      <div className={styles.gallery}>
        <h1>Gallery</h1>
        <ImageList cols={6} rowHeight={320}>
          {this.state.countryList.map((data, idx) => (
            <ImageListItem key={idx} className={styles.imageItem}>
              <Link to="/item" onClick={() => this.handleClick(data.key)}>
                <img src={data.image} width={320} />
                <ItemDetail id={this.state.key}></ItemDetail>
              </Link>
              <ImageListItemBar
                title={"Braintube"}
                subtitle={data.key}
                actionIcon={<FavoriteBorder fontSize="large" color="pink" />}
                actionPosition="top"
              />
            </ImageListItem>
          ))}
        </ImageList>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

I expect that

```
<ItemDetail id={this.state.key}></ItemDetail>
```

passes the state value to the child component itemDetail.

Here is my Routing Path from index.js

```
  <Router>
      <Header childToParent={childToParent}/>
     
      <Switch>
            <Route path="/" exact={true}>
                <Home></Home></Route>
            <Route path="/project-space">
                <ProjectSpace childToParent={wallet}></ProjectSpace> 
            </Route>
            <Route path="/about">
                <About></About></Route>
            <Route path="/item"><ItemDetail></ItemDetail></Route>
            </Switch>
           
     
      <FooterMain></FooterMain>
    </Router>
```

Comment: You had syntax errors, I fixed them

Comment: First of all, why would adding a prop to some child change the data on a different route?

Comment: When child component is mounted the key is empty (pass an empty value). I want to re-render the parent component so that the child component receives the updated props. It's a simple gallery view and I want to pass the selected image-id to the details-child-component.

Comment: Changing state will automatically rerender, no need to redirect

Comment: But I want call a new page...with the passed value. The selected value is the headline of the new page-site

Comment: @Konrad Your edit moved the method definitions outside of the class. Fixed.

Comment: @cbox then use your router or location handler to do that. state isn't for that

Comment: You say "*a link that takes them to another page*". What does this other page have to do with the `<ItemDetail />` that **was** shown next to the link, before it was clicked? If you want to link to different pages showing different things, you should fix the `to="/item"` attribute of the `<Link>`. Then make your router show those different things depending on the location.

Comment: Can you please [edit] your question to show us your routing code?

Comment: Maybe I try to change the question. How can values be passed between 2 pages if the value can only be determined with onClick and onClick should also refer to the new page "simultaneously".

Comment: Router: `<Route path="/item/:id"><ItemDetail></ItemDetail></Route>`, ItemDetails: `const { id } = this.props;` and `const ItemDetailWithRouter= withRouter(ItemDetail);`, IGallery : `<Link to={'/item/' + this.state.key}>`

Comment: This works. Thank you mate. No StateChange needed. <Link to={"/item/" + data.key}>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think we need to take a step back and understand the React paradigm to answer this question.

In React, state goes only one way and is not retained when a component is unmounted. Right now, we have the following

Router > SomePage > IGallery (State = ....)

and we're trying to redirect to:

Router > ItemPage

As you can see here, moving away to ItemPage will drop state because Router will re-render and SomePage will be unmounted.

Therefore, we have two options:

- Pass this item id in the url parameter which will then be handled by the next page
- Move the state to the router parent and pass the state's setter + getter  down to the page components (unrecommended)

For your situation, option one is more intuitive.